# Example for the set that is open connected but not path-connected in $R^n$

Tags: general-topology

Connected set may not be path-connected.

Certainly,there are many examples to show it is true, such as the closure of topologist's sine curve.

> More examples can be found in the following questions posted in this
>   website:
>
> [Is there a topological group that is connected but not
>   path-connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501049/is-there-a-topological-group-that-is-connected-but-not-path-connected)
>
> [Show that this set is connected but not path connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284487/show-that-this-set-is-connected-but-not-path-connected)
>
> [Another example of a connected but non path connected set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005925/another-example-of-a-connected-but-non-path-connected-set)
>
> [connected but not path connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716581/connected-but-not-path-connected)

However, all examples are close connected sets.

So is there any open connected sets that is not path-connected? If not , how to prove the theorem?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Open in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Yes,exactly. Oh,I forget to give topology space. @JohnMa

Comment: Your question is answered essentially here: [A connected locally path connected topological space is path connected](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332108/showing-that-every-connected-open-set-in-a-locally-path-connected-space-is-path).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, then it is easy to see that every *path-connected component* of $A$ is also open. Therefore, if $A$ has at least two path-connected components, then it is a disjoint union of at least two nonempty open sets, and therefore is not connected.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Connected + locally path-connected = path-connected, right?

Comment: @Syuizen: Yes, that sounds right.

Comment: If not in $R^n$ , could such set exist? I mean topology may be very weird.

Comment: @Syuizen: Sure -- just take a known connected-but-not-path-connected set to be the entire topological space, and let $A$ be all of it...

Comment: Uh, subspace topology works. Thank you. I thought that I could find the set in some well-known topology space, but failed.